# connection String Error database in c#

Tags: c#, sql, connection-string

I downloaded a project from the web with its database. I run the project and add its database to tab server on VS 2008 Sp1 and have SQl server 2008.

But when I copy a new connection string to the program, I get the following error message:

> Unrecognized escape sequence

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
namespace AzmongirSource
{
class cl 

   {

    static public  string idstudent;
    static public string userteacher;
    static public string nameazmon;
    static public string codeazmon;

    static public string azmon_typ;
    static public string azmon_for_test_type;
    static public string time_limit;
    static public string tedade_soalat;

    static public  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    static public  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    static public  SqlDataReader reader;
    static public  int truequestion = 0, falsequestion = 0, noquestion = 0;


    static public  void creatconnection()
    {

        connection.Close();
        connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=WINXPX86-BE;AttachDbFilename=D:\payegah\azmoongir_data.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
    }
   static public  DataTable StudentList()
    {
        creatconnection();
        string query = "Select idstu as[شماره دانشجویی],namestu as [نام],familystu as [نام خانوادگی],standardcode as [کداستاندارد],reshte as [رشته] from tbl_student";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, cl.connection);
        DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dtt);
        connection.Close();
        return dtt;

    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape *backslashes* in your connection string, or use `@`

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=WINXPX86-BE;AttachDbFilename=D:\payegah\azmoongir_data.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
```

Documentation: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

By default \ is considered to be an escape character. To avoid that add @ before your connecting string.like

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=WINXPX86-BE;AttachDbFilename=D:\payegah\azmoongir_data.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @ symbol before your connection string

```
@--->Escape characters
```

---

```
connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=WINXPX86-BE;AttachDbFilename=D:\payegah\azmoongir_data.MDF;Integrated Security=True";
```